# Domain class findAll invalid query - query syntax

Tags: grails

I am trying to use `findAll` with query string with mysql. Same query works fine from mysql workbench. Really appreciate any pointers, thanks.

```
//find all subscriptions expiring 7 days from now
Subscription.findAll("from subscription where expires=date_add(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)")
```

Error:

```
Invalid query [from subscription where expires=date_add(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)] for domain class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `findAll` takes [HQL](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#hql) instead of plain SQL.

There are plenty of methods to write your query. `findAllBy` and [**`TimeCategory`**](http://groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html) should do the job:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory    

use( TimeCategory ) {
    Subscription.findAllByExpires(7.days.from.now)
}
```

I assume that `Subscription` domain class has property `expires`.